# Dope Sheet mode in 2.8 : is it possible to display Grease Pencil & regular Dope Sheet keys at the same time?

Tags: keyframes, grease-pencil, dopesheet

Is it possible to display at the same time "regular" keyframes from the Dope Sheet (eg. camera) and grease pencil keyframes, in Blender 2.8 ?

When retiming an animation, it is not very intuitive (and takes more steps) to toggle between those modes.

Any chance you can do both at the same time ?  Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no way, for now, to display several Dope sheet editing contexts in the same area. The best you can do is to stack two dope sheets and give them each editing context you need:

[image: demo pic]

Maybe this could be a nice feature request though.